# How to format proc tabulate to produce decimal millions?

Tags: sas, format, rounding, proc, tabulate

My data is in the format of million and I need to tabulate my data as decimal millions in SAS.

I have data containing rent in millions of dollars i.e. 1,260,678.21 which I hope to tabulate as decimal millions i.e "1.3".

I attempted to create my own function to divide by as follows:

```
           /***/
* create a function to round 
*;

      proc fcmp outlib=work.function.sample;
      function round1000x(value);
      return(round(value/1000000,1));
      endsub; 
      run; 

  *
  * make function available
  *;
  options cmplib=work.func;

   *
   * create a format that uses the function
   *;
   proc format; 
     value round1000x.;
   run; 


 /*use this format in a proc tabulate statement*/

 proc tabulate data=my_data format=round1000x.;
var rent_cost;
table rent_cost;
  run;
```

However I am getting the error:

```
ERROR: The format ROUND1000X has a label that defines another format to be 
 loaded (named ROUND1000X), but this format could not be 
   successfully loaded (possibly for the same reason).
```

Would anyone be familiar with this problem?

Comment: Your VALUE statement does NOT look correct to me. Are you sure that syntax is correct?

Comment: As @Tom pointed out, your code has syntactical errors. There is a straight of the bat example in the SAS documentation site that you could tweak and use: https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n0kl9qj532rbqln187us4ao371h7.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view that scales the value to the desired magnitude and tabulate that.

Example:

```
data have;
  do street = 1 to 50;
    rent = 7e5 + street * 1e5;
    output;
  end;
run;

data forTabulate / view=forTabulate;
  set have;
  rentM = round (rent / 1e6, 0.01);
run;

proc tabulate data=forTabulate;
  class street;
  var rentM;
  table street, rentM*sum='($M)'*f=5.2;
run;
```